What does sourceLocale actually do?
The official description for sourceLocale is quite brief:

Use the Angular CLI to set the source language in which you are writing the component template and code.
By default, Angular uses en-US as the source locale of your project.

So sourceLocale specifies the source language for component templates and code. But what it actually does? What happens if I change it? What parts of the application does it affect?

Gist: The build process (described in Merge translations into the app in this guide) uses your app's angular.json file to automatically set the LOCALE_ID token and load the locale data though sourceLocale field.
I checked the source code.
The best reference was from this old documentation

The Angular repository includes common locales. You can change your app's source locale for the build by setting the source locale in the sourceLocale field of your app's workspace configuration file (angular.json). The build process (described in Merge translations into the app in this guide) uses your app's angular.json file to automatically set the LOCALE_ID token and load the locale data.

Other references:
translator.ts


@param sourceLocale The locale of the original application source. If provided then an
additional copy of the application is created under this locale just with the $localize calls
stripped out.


